# This revision of snap "flutter" was published using classic confinement

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

error: This revision of snap "flutter" was published using classic confinement
and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security
sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at
risk.

```
   If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including
   --classic.
```

Answer (score -2):

NOTE : This revision of snap "flutter" was published using classic confinement and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at risk.

If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --classic.

Command linux: sudo snap install flutter --classic